# Open a new ViewController from a current view controller

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, storyboard

I know there are a few other question out there like this, however I'm not able to get any of them to work.  I think I need a little more clarification that I'm attacking this correctly.

I have a story board that I have a NavigationController on with a segue to a ViewController that contains a webview.  I have successfully captured the the click on my webview and I would like it to open in a new ViewController that also contains a webview.  I have added a second ViewController with a webview on to my storyboard, but can't figure out how to add a segue to it.  I also tried making the connection in the code by adding the following to my shouldStartLoadWithRequest method of my first ViewController:

```
    SecondViewController *secondViewController = [[SecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondViewController" bundle:nil];
    [self presentViewController:secondViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

However it never opens my second ViewController, it just stays in the first ViewController.  I'm a noob and I'm sure I'm missing something somewhere?

Comment: Yes, By "using" I have it on my storyboard connected to my first view controller.

Comment: ok where you put this code in some button event or somewhere else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add the segue from one view controller to the other (not connected to any specific button), and then give the segue an identifier.

Then, in your code, remove the `initWithNibName`, because you don't have a NIB. Instead, use `performSegueWithIdentifier:sender:`. You will also likely want to use `prepareForSegue:sender:` in order to pass the appropriate URL / HTML information that should be loaded into the second web view.

Comment: I have tried dragging a segue from the first view controller, and the webview of the first view controller to the second and it won't let me? How do you add a segue that isn't connected to something like a button?

Comment: In the bar below the view, you see an orange / yellow circle representing the view controller. Ctrl-drag from that to the destination view

Comment: That worked thanks! I just looked up the use of performSegueWithIdentifier:sender and I'm alittle confused by the use of it.  Am I using it as a method like this?  - (bool)performSegueWithIdentifier:sender
{
    
}

Comment: `[self performSegue...` because the segue is connected to the controller itself